# Question about equivalence between these two Ginzburg-Landau equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I'm going through [this](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Epavl/BlomHairPav05.pdf) paper and I'm stuck at showing the equivalence between the follwoing two equations:

[image: (1.4)]
[image]

where the first equation for $\alpha$ is the respective (1.4). In particular, I can't prove that

$4\partial^2_X  \alpha= -4(i\partial_x+\delta_\epsilon)^2A \quad (*)$

And what is worse, I can not even understand how the rhs of $(*)$ will give me a second order derivative anyways. At the end of the day, all I get is $(\partial_x \alpha)^2$ with some extra terms.

Any help is much appreciated! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: \begin{align}
a &\to A e^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x} \\
\partial_{x} a &\to \partial_{x} A e^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x} - i \delta_{\epsilon} A e^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x} \\
\partial_{xx} a &\to \partial_{xx} A e^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x}-2i\delta_{\epsilon}\partial_{x}Ae^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x} - \delta_{\epsilon}^{2} A e^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x} \\
&=(\partial_{x} - i \delta_{\epsilon})^{2} A e^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x} \\
&=(i (-i) \partial_{x} - i \delta_{\epsilon})^{2} A e^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x} \\
&=- (i \partial_{x} + \delta_{\epsilon})^{2} A e^{-i \delta_{\epsilon} x} \\
\end{align}

Comment: @MatthewCassell many thanks for the comment. But why is $\partial_{xx}$ equal to $(\partial_x)^2$? That is the part that confused me in the first place. Is it because $\partial_{xx}= \partial_x(\partial_x)$ and hence for the differential operator $T:=\partial_x$ it holds that $T^2(u)=T(T(u))$?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Notation), $\partial_{xx} f = \partial_{x}^{2} f = \partial_{x} (\partial_{x} f)$.